# Trigger is not fired When Bulk insertion happened through Import Data option in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have created a table along with trigger, When I am trying to Import the data to SQL server from Excel, trigger is not fired When Bulk insertion happened through Import Data option in SQL Server 2017